# Constant binding to event listener Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, event-listener

I am having a bit of an issue. I want to bind elements (in Jquery) to an event Listener.
I would normally do it in the `$(document).ready()` but these elements are not created yet in the body, so they are not binded with the event listeners.
I would like to know if there is a way of doing this so I don't have to bind the elements every time I create a new element.

The elements are created like this : `$("#theDiv").html(functionReturningHTMLString())`

Thank you all

Comment: [So much information available](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+jquery+bind+events+after+load&gws_rd=ssl) if you care to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the events via [`$.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) even if the elements are not in the DOM yet.

I'm assuming you were trying to use `$.click` which can only be used for elements that already exist in the DOM.